Jupyter notebook module not found python3
I am receiving this module error while using jupyter notebook:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sisl
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16

Emin, Emax = -15, 15


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33660/856295374.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 import sisl
      4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      5 plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sisl'

However: sisl it is successfully installed as version 0.11 as you can see from here:
(base) my@my-laptop:~$ sisl --version
/home/path/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py:146: UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.23.2
  warnings.warn(f"A NumPy version >={np_minversion} and <{np_maxversion}"
sisl: 0.11.0
git-hash: 0

I googled and looked on various examples such as: this one, this one and also this one
I also made sure the path is added on my gedit ~/.bashrc
And in fact here is a quick overview :
`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/path/Downloads/Siesta/Slides_Tutorials/All/Tutorials-2021/DFT-TB/"`

For completeness I am also attaching a print screen for you to see:

Can anybody see what the problem might be and try to point me in the right direction?

Sounds like you have more than one installation of python on your computer, and jupyter notebook is configured to use the wrong one.

Running the command to check the version of sisl in the terminal really tells you nothing about if the environment Jupyter is using has access to where sisl is involved. Run the magic command %conda list in a cell in the notebook where you are trying to import it and see what that says. It will probably not be listed. If you don't want to take the time to properly connect the correct kernel and environment and want to be past this hurdle, you can run the magic install %conda install conda-forge::sisl in a cell in the notebook and see if that will help install it. The magic install ...

 commands insure that the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. As for proper connecting, see the top two answers here. The three links you refer to, most don't seem related to Anaconda/conda, which is involved because you choose to make Anaconda/conda your primary package manager by using miniconda, as seen in your path in your post, even though you neglect providing details on how you installed things in your post.
